# grunt + sass: output 2 css files at the same time

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

I would like to have grunt compile a compact and a compressed version of my sass.  I can get it to compile one or the other but not both at the same time.  I have tried:

```
sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'style.min.css': 'css/main.scss',
            }
        }
    },

    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compact'
            },
            files: {
                'style.css': 'css/main.scss',
            }
        }
    }
```

and also:

```
sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'style.min.css': 'css/main.scss',
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compact'
            },
            files: {
                'style.css': 'css/main.scss',
            }
        }
    }
```

But neither has worked.  What's the solution?

Comment: You can also use other grunt task just to compress your style as https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the approach I take in my projects, I could be dead wrong about it but I have similar intention as to create one file for *readability* and other for *minification* purposes.

```
sass: {
  appStyles: {options: {style: 'expanded', sourcemap: 'none'}, files: {'styles/app.css': 'styles/app/main.scss'}},
  appStylesMinified: {options: {style: 'compressed', sourcemap: 'none'}, files: {'styles/app.min.css': 'styles/app.css'}}
}
```

Notice that the `style` that I have chosen for both `appStyles` and `appStylesMinified` are `expanded` and `compressed` respectively. Also, the `compressed` version takes the newly created `app.css` file instead of `main.scss` to further create `app.min.css`.

I find this `app.css` a little useful in debugging as well when I am still in development mode. But of course, when everything is production ready, `app.min.css` takes it from there.

Comment: thanks @TahirAhmed, that worked beautifully.  I'm new to grunt so I didn't realise you could customise declarations like appStyles (I'm assuming it's custom since I didn't find that in the documentation).  Thanks for solving my issue and educating me at the same time!

Comment: Glad it helped. Yes the declarations `appStyles` and `appStylesMinified` are custom and changeable. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to compact the saas files you can directly use `@import` in your saas files and your single will be ready and then use compress. Just create something like main.scss and import all the saas files inside it and then compress this fle instead.

Edited:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: {
        'main.css': 'main.scss',
        'main1.css': 'main1.scss'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Kushal, thanks for the response.  If I may clarify my question, I would like sass to output two css files at once, both a readable css file and and minified css file when I run grunt.  I am already doing what you are suggesting using imports in my main scss file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find the following code works just fine.
Instead of relying on sass to output multiple files with different compression, I have sass output the compact style and then use `grunt-contrib-cssmin` to compress the css even further.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compact'
        },
        files: {
          'style.css': 'css/main.scss',
          'style1.css': 'css/main1.scss',
        }
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'style.min.css': ['style.css'],
          'style1.min.css': ['style1.css']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'cssmin']);

};
```

You don't even need the compact option. This would make the output css more easily readable.